# some thing wrong with array index in byte[]

Tags: java

I have string like this

```
String text = "f001050000000000003d61c1c1df400200c0000009181600ef014000003f20"
```

I converted it to bytes to loop through it as bytes

```
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(text,16).toByteArray();        
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) 
    {            
        System.out.print(String.format("%02x ", bytes[i]));
    }
```

But when I print array values it adds byte `00` at the beginning of the actual string!
It should start with `f0` but it starts with `00`!

When I start index with `1` this `00` disappear.
From where this `00` come!?

Comment: Why shouldn't it start with `00`? You assumed it wouldn't, but you had no right to that assumption. `BigInteger` is designed for integers, and they can be positive or negative. You are seeing a artifact of this. HINT: try this with a string that starts out `7F` and then one that starts out `80`. You should read the Javadocs for BigInteger and stop making assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JavaDoc of BigInteger#toByteArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29) states:

> Returns a byte array containing the **two's-complement
>   representation** of this BigInteger. The byte array will be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element. The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger, including at least one sign bit, which is `(ceil((this.bitLength() + 1)/8))`.[...]

As you have a positive number, the first bit will be zero in two's complement.

Comment: Thanks @jlordo, is there is another way to create a byte array without this `00`

Comment: As the array will contain the minimum number of bytes needed, you have to use a number that needs `n` bits, with `n % 8 == 0`

Comment: I need the array to be the actual size of bytes because I will do other operations on it.

Comment: If it bothers you do much, manually remove it. Note that the BigInteger representation is as small as possible for two's compliment representation, so if there is a leading all zeroes byte it's only to make sure it's interpreted with the corrected signedness - if you turn into a BigInteger something starting with many zeroes, they will be gone anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think BigInteger is no good for this task. You need to parse your text yourself, it's not difficult

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[text.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) ((Character.digit(text.charAt(i * 2), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(text.charAt(i * 2 + 1), 16));
    }
```

not that it also converts "0000f0..." correctly but BigInteger would truncate leading zeroes (normalize) because for BigInteger it is just a number